# GEE Python API method 'prepare_for_export' not available

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api, attributeerror

I want to prepocess a batch of Sentinel-2 images using the [code provided by ndminhhus](https://github.com/ndminhhus/geeguide/blob/master/jupyter_notebooks/02.Atm-corr-Sentinel2.ipynb). Earth Engine authentication, Py6S, custom module "atmospheric", basically all necessary modules have been installed and updated. The code seems to connect to functions in [batch.py](https://github.com/google/earthengine-api/blob/master/python/ee/batch.py). This script uses the GEE Python API method prepare_for_export() (as stated in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs)). Below are the relevant snippets:

From ndminhhus:

```
fname = ee.String(img.get('system:index')).getInfo()
export = ee.batch.Export.image.toAsset(\
    image=ref,
    description= 'S2_BOA_'+fname,
    assetId = 'users/Bmperezaraujo/Py6S_Harmonisation'+'S2_BOA'+fname,
    region = region,
    scale = 10,
    maxPixels = 1e13)

# uncomment to run the export
export.start()
print('exporting ' +fname + '--->done')
```

From batch.py:

```
def _prepare_image_export_config(image, config, export_destination):
  """Performs all preparation steps for an image export.

  Args:
    image: The Image to be exported.
    config: All the user-specified export parameters. May be modified.
    export_destination: One of the Task.ExportDestination values.

  Returns:
    A config dict containing all information required for the export.
  """
  # Supply some defaults.
  if (export_destination != Task.ExportDestination.ASSET and
      'fileFormat' not in config):
    config['fileFormat'] = 'GeoTIFF'

  _canonicalize_parameters(config, export_destination)

  image, config = image.prepare_for_export(config)
  # Build an ExportImageRequest. Delete values from "config" as we go so we
  # can check at the end for any leftovers. Any computed objects will be
  # serialised in data.py before the request is sent.
  request = {}
  request['expression'] = image
  if 'description' in config:
    request['description'] = config.pop('description')

  if export_destination == Task.ExportDestination.ASSET:
    asset_export_options = {}
    asset_export_options[
        'earthEngineDestination'] = _build_earth_engine_destination(config)
    # This can only be set by internal users.
    if 'tileSize' in config and 'shardSize' in config:
      raise ee_exception.EEException(
          'Both "shardSize" and "tileSize" cannot be set.')
    if 'tileSize' in config:
      asset_export_options['tileSize'] = {
          'value': int(config.pop('tileSize'))}
    # "shardSize" is the old name for "tileSize".
    if 'shardSize' in config:
      asset_export_options['tileSize'] = {'value': int(config.pop('shardSize'))}
    if 'pyramidingPolicy' in config:
      pyramiding_policy = config.pop('pyramidingPolicy')
      if '.default' in pyramiding_policy:
        asset_export_options[
            'pyramidingPolicy'] = pyramiding_policy.pop('.default').upper()
      if pyramiding_policy:
        asset_export_options['pyramidingPolicyOverrides'] = {
            band: policy.upper() for band, policy in pyramiding_policy.items()
        }
    request['assetExportOptions'] = asset_export_options
  else:
    request['fileExportOptions'] = _build_image_file_export_options(
        config, export_destination)

  if 'maxPixels' in config:
    # This field is an Int64Value, so it needs an inner "value" field, and
    # the value itself is a string, not an integer, in the JSON encoding.
    request['maxPixels'] = {'value': str(int(config.pop('maxPixels')))}

  # This can only be set by internal users.
  if 'maxWorkers' in config:
    request['maxWorkers'] = {'value': int(config.pop('maxWorkers'))}

  # Of the remaining fields in ExportImageRequest:
  # - All the values that would go into the PixelGrid should have been folded
  #   into the image's Expression.
  # - The request ID will be populated when the Task is created.
  # We've been deleting config parameters as we handle them. Anything left
  # over is a problem.
  if config:
    raise ee_exception.EEException(
        'Unknown configuration options: {}.'.format(config))

  return request
```

Upon running my code, I receive the error:

> AttributeError: 'Element' object has no attribute 'prepare_for_export'

I have double-checked that my input img is of ee.image.Image type.

I have a functioning GEE Python API.

I checked whether batch has the prepare_for_export method with `hasattr(ee.batch, 'prepare_for_export')`, but it returned me a negative.

How can I import the missing GEE Python API method?

Comment: The function you should be calling is ee.batch.Export.image.toAsset https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/export-image-toasset

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can delete the code below:

```
 dateString = scene_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
 ref = ref.copyProperties(img).set({              
                  'AC_date':dateString,
                  'AC_aerosol_optical_thickness':aot,
                  'AC_water_vapour':h2o,
                  'AC_version':'py6S',
                  'AC_contact':'ndminhhus@gmail.com',
                  'AC_ozone':o3})
```

Then you try it, it maybe succeed!